# Repair broken link from tree to blob in git repository

Tags: git

I have an issue with my git repository being broken. Originally, there was an error saying there is an empty object file. After searching a bit, I decided to delete that file.
After doing that, this is the current error I have when using `fsck`:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree 22af4e0d7f618abb54ba2d62092f931826414f48
              to    blob 9a97b09b64d81d0cca2501a0733ac1d0be71581c
dangling blob 36740f0f2e6ddbb8745b0fcb4897bad879f8fe40
dangling blob ee70f4c8d5b294e23e00e931ba378cbbb6087e50
dangling blob 667af6c0ec7d2ea1e5951c41c1262640c74ed1ff
dangling blob 0c074bcac363a842fe42ff4286c4be8fe3973d7b
dangling blob 2c13ab681c81d8c3ea0cf9f588896e783be8dacb
dangling blob 93a73bcf2ea8c946dac6285de673f6e8ba3773d5
missing blob 9a97b09b64d81d0cca2501a0733ac1d0be71581c
dangling blob b5efe74528cf6a826bedcda3013f87f2e8740247
```

I have no clue how to proceed now. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "Dangling" items in a Git repository are normal. The missing one is the real problem. You'll have to obtain it from some other clone of the same repository. If there are no other clones, look for a backup or some other outside-Git method of recovering the missing data.

Comment: Sadly this is a local project with no other backups. I was about to set up a bitbucket repository and then I came across this error. Is there any way to recover something from this repo? Even if it means the loss of part of the history? The history is relatively short and all my actual code is safe

Comment: You should be able to `git checkout` every commit that doesn't have the missing object. You may be even able to check out the commit(s) that do use it, minus that missing file of course. You could use this to build a new repository with some commits.

Comment: But how can I find a commit before this missing object? As both 22af4e and 9a97b0 are not a commit. And if I do manage to find a commit without this missing object, do I have to rebase on that commit?

Comment: A `git log` or `git rev-list` starting from branch names and working backwards, without any requests to examine the *files* in each commit (hence no need to look at tree objects), should produce all the commit hashes reachable from those names. Use `--topo-order` to keep them in graph topology order (and/or add `--graph` to a `git log --oneline`). That will show you the commit graph structure. From there you can work out which commits refer to the now-missing object, and which don't.

Comment: Remember, a repository is just a big database of Git objects. The *interesting* objects are mostly the commits, which contain only the metadata and a *reference to* a tree object. If the metadata suggest that the commit's tree is interesting, *then* you have Git retrieve the top level tree, and from that, all the sub-trees and their blob hashes and that produces the snapshot for that commit. Now that you have a broken repository, you're going to have to throw away that repository—but first you'll presumably want to salvage as much of each interesting snapshot as possible.

Comment: You can take those salvaged snapshots and use them to build a new (not-broken) repository, with whatever history you like. History, in any Git repository, is nothing more or less than the set of commits in the repository.